# How do I prevent dnsmasq from appending my domain name to invalid domain requests?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I use [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) to resolve DNS queries on my home network. Unfortunately, if a domain name is not known, it will append my own domain name to the request which means that I always end up viewing my own site in a browser.

For example, if I enter http://dlksfhoiahdsfiuhsdf.com in a browser, I end up viewing my own site with that URL. If I try something like:

```
host dlksfhoiahdsfiuhsdf.com
```

Instead of the expected:

```
Host dlksfhoiahdsfiuhsdf.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

I get this:

```
dlksfhoiahdsfiuhsdf.com.mydomainname.com has address W.X.Y.Z.
```

Clearly, dnsmasq is appending my domain name to impossible name requests in an effort to resolve them, but I'd rather see the not found error instead.

I've tried playing with the *expand-hosts* and *domain* configuration settings, but to no avail. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 3):

try querying with a trailing dot to explicitly set the root:

```
host dlksfhoiahdsfiuhsdf.com.
```

Answer (score 3):

It is probably not dnsmasq doing it, but your local resolver library.  If you use a unixish, try removing the "search" or "domain" lines from /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In the time since I asked the question, I've stopped using dnsmasq and so I can't test your solution. I'll leave it up in case it can be of help to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

There might be other causes, but the most obvious cause is the configuration of /etc/resolv.conf, and the fact that most DNS clients like to be very terse about errors.

```
benc$ host thing.one
Host thing.one not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

(okay, what was I using for a DNS config?)

```
benc$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

(edit...)

```
benc$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search test.com
nameserver 192.168.1.1
benc$ host thing.one
thing.one.test.com has address 64.214.163.132
```

Without bothering to do a packet trace, the likely behavior is that it returns the error for the last FQDN it tried.

Answer (score 1):

You have a wildcard domain?

dnsmasq is forwarding the appended name out to the external dns server and its getting wildcarded.

you can use --server=/yourinternaldomainhere/ to make sure that your internal domain name lookups are not forwarded out.

syntax in this case would be:

--server=/domain/iptoforwardto

and in this case leave the iptoforwardto area blank as you don't want it to forward anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing *domain-needed* from my own configuration to replicate your issue and it did not produce this behaviour.  It's the only other parameter I could find that might be close to relevant.

What does your hosts file look like?  Maybe something weird is going on there that makes it think all weird domains are local to your network?